# How can I get the name of the script calling the function in python?

Tags: python

I know that `__file__` contains the filename containing the code, but is there a way to get the name of the script/file that's calling the function?

If I have a file named `filenametest_b.py`:

```
def printFilename():
    print(__file__)
```

And I import the function in `filenametest_a.py`:

```
from filenametest_b import *

printFilename()
```

I get:

```
C:\Users\a150495>python filenametest_a.py
C:\Users\a150495\filenametest_b.py
```

Is there something I can do in the `b` file to print the name of the `a` file?

Comment: you could probably parse `sys.argv[0]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could print `sys.argv[0]` to get the script filename.

To get the filename of the caller, you need to use the [`sys._getframe()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys._getframe) to get the calling frame, then you can retrieve the filename from that:

```
import inspect, sys

print inspect.getsourcefile(sys, sys._getframe(1))
```

Comment: `inspect.getsourcefile(sys._getframe(1))` works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Asked a bit too soon, I think I just solved it.

I was just looking around in the `inspect` module:

I added this to the `filenametest_b.py` file:

```
def printCaller():
    frame,filename,line_number,function_name,lines,index=\
        inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe())[1]
    print(frame,filename,line_number,function_name,lines,index)
```

which gives this:

```
C:\Users\a150495\filenametest_b.py
(<frame object at 0x000000000231D608>, 'filenametest_a.py', 5, '<module>', ['printCaller()\n'], 0)
```

So this should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
def printFilename():
    import traceback 
    print traceback.extract_stack()[-2][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

this work for me:

```
    inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe())[1].filename
```